# Exception thrown when one parameter of an Oracle stored function is null

Tags: hibernate, plsql, persistence, named-query

I want o call a PL/SQL function using a named query.
One of the parameters causes me problems. In the PL/SQL definition its type is NUMBER.
Here is the Java code where it is set:
`q.setParameter (Test.DISTRICT_ID_PARAM,districtId);`
and `districtId` is a `Long`.

When `districtId` is not null everything is ok, but when it is null this is the outcome:
`org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query`

I'm sure there's no problem with the plumbing since the query works well when `districtId` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Java or Hibernate specifically, but in Oracle applications I've written I've come across similar behaviour with null parameters (C#) - if Java has the concept, have you tried setting the parameter value to be DB null (in C# DBNull.Value)?

If the value is null I think Oracle interprets it as the parameter not being passed at all.

Comment: The DB function accepts another 3 parameters of type VARCHAR2. I set those the same way I do with the previous one and everything works well, even if they are null. What I am trying to find out is whether there is something different when it comes to NUMBER parameters.

Comment: @RaduStoenescu: From PL/SQL parameter passing point of view there is no difference when passing null parameter to type varchar2 or number.

Comment: @MarkWatts: If you pass a parameter with a null value to PL/SQL function the function sees that parameter and the value of the parameter is null.

Comment: @user272735 That is true when calling PL/SQL directly (e.g. via SQL*Plus or similar) but when making calls to Oracle via code there is, certainly in .Net, a difference between defining a parameter value as null and DBNull.Value. Using null yields the error ORA-01008. However, this seems to be true for both VARCHAR2 and NUMBER types, so it can probably be ruled out as the source of Radu's problem.